# Search-Engine Friendly URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, seo, search-engine

I am working on building my first search-engine friendly CMS. I know that perhaps one of the biggest keys to having and SEO site is to have search-engine friendly URLs. So having a link like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/product/details/page1
```

will result in much better rankings than one like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?pageID=37
```

I know that to create URLs like the first one, I have one of two options:

- use a web technology, in this case PHP, to create a directory structure
- leverage Apache's `mod_rewrite` add-on to have these URLs passed to a PHP processor

As far as the PHP goes, I'm pretty comfortable with anything. However, I think the first option would be more difficult to maintain.

Could someone show me how to write an `.htaccess` file, which will:

- silently direct SEO URLs to a processor script
- not redirect if the requested URL is an actual directory on the server

Is there a better way than the way I am trying it?

Comment: Here's a good [**tutorial**](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) about mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use .htaccess for apache, create file in your root folder of web mainly "htdocs" name it ".htaccess" add next content to it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

in your php file you can access data from $_GET

```
$_GET['url'];
```

Then you can use data to parse what you need.

Comment: ok, I *seriously* need to learn Apache. Thanks for the sample Senad!!! If you have an extra moment, could you fill me in on what each part does?

Comment: IfModule checks does mod_rewrite.c exists on server
RewriteEngine On turns it on.
RewriteCondition is condition, what to rewrite
Reqrite rule what to do with the rewritten data (taking all after .com and puting it into server variables and executes index.php, yes that is all you need to understand for now

Comment: Drupal has very similar rewriting fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first option would be pretty hard to maintain. If you want to change the header of the pages, you'd need to recalculate *all* of the pages.

The simplest way to do that would be to have a PHP file named `product.php` or `product/details.php` and use the [`$_SERVER\['PATH_INFO'\]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable to figure out what the client requested.

Comment: thanks, but the only problem with this approach is that these fake-directory structures will be created on the fly, and could totally change. I do agree that it would be a headache to have PHP try to maintain.