# Showing the desired url in address bar but actually not

Tags: php, smarty

I am seeking a way that when the user click on a link.. it should go to that address but should show my desired url in the address bar..

Is there any procedure in php & smarty.

Please help me. i am new ti this condition,

Comment: like in smarty.. we have url goal=something&mode=something...

Comment: I think using an iframe would be your best option but I could be wrong.

Comment: but i want www.mysite.com/mypage.html

Comment: I think you are looking for pretty urls! http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

Comment: my client is demanding that he should be able to see different pages links , but don`t want to create the html pages one by one.. the content in each page should be changed like CMS. but the address should be also somethinh.htnl

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search-Engine Friendly URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102129/search-engine-friendly-urls) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+friendly+urls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "fake" a url in the address bar; that would be a big security issue. It would enable you to show "mybank.com" whilst being on an evil site...

What you're probably referring to is something like [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) or using a [frameset or iFrame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frameset).

Comment: history.pushstate begs to differ

Comment: @Dale ...and that allows you to modify the contents of the address bar while not actually surfing to that url?? And I'm not talking about the path, I'm talking about the domain part.

Comment: Sorry there Rob I misunderstood

Comment: my client is demanding that he should be able to see different pages links , but don`t want to create the html pages one by one.. the content in each page should be changed like CMS. but the address should be also somethinh.htnl

Comment: @RobIII Frameset is deprecated, and probably shouldn't be recommended.

Comment: @CoolSporty That is just a matter of rewriting / redirecting .html urls to the PHP preprocessor. Check [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon I am not actually recommending it ;-)

Comment: But if you change the DNS you can fake the url right?

Answer (score 1):

Php and Smarty I don't know but you can do anything with url's if you use a .htaccess file.
E.g. assign an other page to your URL so www.myDomain/index.php?pageID=1 will be www.myDomain/someProductname.

To learn to implement and use this, there are a lot of resources.
Here's a basic: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/