# How to build an SEO friendly website URLs from dynamic database content?

Tags: php, dynamic, web, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search-Engine Friendly URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102129/search-engine-friendly-urls)

I have just finished collecting a large quantity of data which I now want to use for dynamically generating content on a website. To do this I will most likely be using PHP.

The site is planned as follows:

One static page (homepage) with a search box. Depending on the search multiple links will be displayed linking to 'detail' pages. The detail pages will be populated from the content within the database and all use the same template.

Think of a list of cars on the homepage and clicking on 'Volkswagon Golf' will take the visitor to a page showing details about the Golf all extracted from the database.

How can I make the detail pages have unique URL's so they can be indexed by robots? IE: www.mysite.com/details/vw_golf

My assumption is if I just redirect to a templating page i'll end up with something like www.mysite.com/details.php?search=volkswagon_golf. Even if I use POST I won't have a static URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's my personal opinion that you should use a framework of some sort, they all do this by default (or at least with little needed configuration).  I mean, while it's not a framework, you could at least look into [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) or [Drupal](http://drupal.org/).

If your plan is to build the entire website yourself without any framework or content management system, then I'd do some research on [Apache `mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  It's tough to give you any code without a specific question.  You're going to need to look into [REGEX](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) if you get into `mod_rewrite` as well.